# Zend Framework check if a controller exists or not

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm looking for a solution to the problem I mentioned in the title.

I have ROUTER and I have an order I check whether the controller exists or not and I can not find a solution.

I did something like this

```
class Plugin_Router extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

    public function routeStartup (Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $dispatcher = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getDispatcher();
        if (!$dispatcher->isDispatchable($request)) {
             // Controller exists

             // Exit ();
             $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
             $router->addRoute('/:catid', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:catid', array(
                 'module' => 'default' ,
                 'controller' => 'profile' ,
                 'action' => '' // Check your action and controller
             )));
         }
    }
}
```

And it does not work there is another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear what this plugin is supposed to do. You've put your logic within `routeStartup()` which happens *before* routing takes place. `isDispatchable()` is always going to return false there, since the module/controller/action to dispatch hasn't yet been determined.

I would say move the logic to `routeShutdown()` (which runs *after* routing), but the purpose of your code seems to be to add a new route if routing fails, which wouldn't achieve anything. You might need to rethink your approach.

You can *change* parameters in the request object before the dispatch occurs, which is probably what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found a half answer:

```
public function routeStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{

    $url = explode("/", substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1));
    $path = APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/' . ucfirst(strtolower($url[0])) .
        'Controller' . '.php';

    if (!file_exists($path)) {

        $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

        $router->addRoute(':catid', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':catid', array(
            'module' => 'default',
            'controller' => 'profile',
            'action' => 'index' // Check your action and controller

            )));

    }
}
```

}

If anyone has a working code on ZEND'd like to hear ....

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I can propose you this (this is inspired by the Dispatcher and Front Controller):

```
public function routeStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request){
{
    //For feeding modules, controllers actions and parameters of $request
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $router->setParams(Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParams());
    $router->route($request);

    // get Module and Controller names
    $dispatcher     = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getDispatcher();
    $controller     = $request->getControllerName();
    $default        = $dispatcher->formatControllerName($controller);
    $module         = $request->getModuleName();
    $controllerDirs = $dispatcher->getControllerDirectory();


    $found = false;
    $fileSpec = '';

    if ($dispatcher->isValidModule($module)) {        
        if (class_exists($default, false)) {
            $found = true;
        } else {
            $moduleDir = $controllerDirs[$module];
            $fileSpec  = $moduleDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dispatcher->classToFilename($default);

            if (Zend_Loader::isReadable($fileSpec)) {
                $found = true;                    
            }
        }
    }

    if ($found) {
    // The controller exists
    ...
    }
}
```